# USB ethernet adapter connected and found in ifconfig, but not working

Tags: networking, drivers, arm

I've bought a USB ethernet adapter for my ARM-Board running debian to have a second interface. I compiled and loaded the driver/module and the device is being recognized:

```
[    5.285487] usb 2-1.3.1: new high speed USB device number 5 using usb20_host
[    5.410218] usb 2-1.3.1: New USB device found, idVendor=0b95, idProduct=1790
[    5.415139] usb 2-1.3.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[    5.419292] usb 2-1.3.1: Product: AX88179
[    5.423656] usb 2-1.3.1: Manufacturer: ASIX Elec. Corp.
[    5.428398] usb 2-1.3.1: SerialNumber: 00803F5AF88883
[   38.570534] ax88179_178a 2-1.3.1:1.0: eth1: register 'ax88179_178a' at usb-usb20_host-1.3.1, ASIX AX88179 USB 3.0 Gigabit Ethernet, 80:4a:56:02:1e:84
```

some more information:

```
lsusb 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. USB-2.0 4-Port HUB
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0bda:0724 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 2109:2812  
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 0b95:1790 ASIX Electronics Corp.
```

Then I ran

```
ifconfig eth1 up
ifconfig eth1 192.168.2.2 netmask 255.255.255.0
```

then showing up as:

```
ifconfig eth1
eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 80:4a:56:02:1e:84  
          inet addr:192.168.2.2  Bcast:192.168.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

But when connected to the ARM-Board the LED on the device (for link and activity) do never show up. Therefore I checked the power consumption (despite the fact that the USB ethernet adapter is connected via an active USB hub):

```
 lsusb -s 002:005 -v | grep MaxPower
    MaxPower              248mA
```

Furthermore, I can't ping the IP form outside, nor I can reach any other PC or gateway in the network. So it seems that I/O isn't working at all. Fully working and also blinking is the adapter when connected to my laptop running opensuse 13.1 (with included drivers). 
Any ideas what could cause this problem?

EDIT2: In the current setup both interfaces are connected to the same switch, I also interchanged the cables and tried in total 5 different ones, all them are working when using the usb adapter with the laptop connecting to the same switch:

```
# ethtool eth1
Settings for eth1:
        Supported ports: [ TP MII ]
        Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                                1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full 
        Supported pause frame use: No
        Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
        Advertised link modes:  Not reported
        Advertised pause frame use: No
        Advertised auto-negotiation: No
        Speed: 10Mb/s
        Duplex: Half
        Port: MII
        PHYAD: 3
        Transceiver: internal
        Auto-negotiation: off
        Supports Wake-on: pg
        Wake-on: g
        Current message level: 0x00000007 (7)
                               drv probe link
        Link detected: no

# ethtool eth0                                                                                                                                                                                                       
Settings for eth0:                                                                                                                                                                                                               
        Supported ports: [ TP MII ]                                                                                                                                                                                              
        Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full                                                                                                                                                                        
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full                                                                                                                                                                      
        Supported pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only                                                                                                                                                                        
        Supports auto-negotiation: Yes                                                                                                                                                                                           
        Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full                                                                                                                                                                        
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full                                                                                                                                                                      
        Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only                                                                                                                                                                       
        Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes                                                                                                                                                                                         
        Speed: 100Mb/s                                                                                                                                                                                                           
        Duplex: Full                                                                                                                                                                                                             
        Port: MII                                                                                                                                                                                                                
        PHYAD: 0                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
        Transceiver: external                                                                                                                                                                                                    
        Auto-negotiation: on                                                                                                                                                                                                     
        Link detected: yes
```

Here some further on the configuration:

```
ifconfig 
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr de:ad:ff:ad:fe:ef  
          inet addr:192.168.178.3  Bcast:192.168.178.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1295 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1115 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:321305 (313.7 KiB)  TX bytes:184021 (179.7 KiB)
          Interrupt:51 

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 80:4a:56:02:1e:84  
          inet addr:192.168.178.10  Bcast:192.168.178.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

# ip addr show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK> mtu 16436 qdisc noop state DOWN 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether de:ad:ff:ad:fe:ef brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.178.3/24 brd 192.168.178.255 scope global eth0
    inet 192.168.2.2/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global eth0
8: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN qlen 1000
    link/ether 80:4a:56:02:1e:84   brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.178.10/24 brd 192.168.178.255 scope global eth1
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure that the routing table and the DNS are correctly configured. To fix the first:

```
  sudo ip route add 192.168.2.0/24 dev eth1
  sudo ip route add default via 192.168.2.1
```

and for the second, as sudo, add the folloing two lines to /etc/resolv.conf

```
   nameserver 8.8.8.8
   nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

Comment: thanks! Indeed there was an issue with the routing which was fixed by this. But I think the main issue is that if I directly connect the ARM-Board via USB adapter to my laptop, the laptop says that there is cable connected.

Comment: @bonanza Most likely, you have forgotten to use a crossover cable rather than a normal ethernet cable.

Comment: I tried a patch and a cross over cable, both without success. Is there anything else besides loading the module and bringing up the device with ifconfig that I have to do to 'wake' up the interface? Edit: the state of ifconfig shown above has been made after several tries of pinging in both directions. So from the statistics there is really nothing going in or out.

Comment: @bonanza Can you give me a few more details? Does your laptop use one or two ethernet bays when you try to do this? Are you using a network manager?  What is the output of *ip addr show* and *ip route show* on the laptop?

Comment: I added some more information in the starting post, please note that the ethtool says for the usb adapter "Link detected: no".